# daul boot between linux and windows

Tags: installation, boot, 64-bit, uefi

I have installed the 32 bit version of ubuntu while I should have installed the 64-bit version of ubuntu. I am trying to have a daul boot between windows 8 and linux. The  problem comes when I am trying to run boot-repair on the 32 bit version of ubuntu and it complains by saying that I need to have a 64-bit version of ubuntu to support the efi system.When I try to download the 64 bit version on my computer, the archive manager stops and claims that there is an error, how do I work around this.

Comment: Where are you running the archive manager from? On the windows OS or on linux?

Comment: I am running it on the 32 bit linux OS

Answer (score 2):

As Rod said, a 64-bit installation is optimal nowadays, especially on systems with Windows 8, where there is an extra layer of protection with the UEFI.

Just download the 64-bit ISO and re-install Ubuntu. Quickest solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Download errors have nothing to do with the firmware or CPU architecture. They're more likely related to network errors, running out of disk space, or other such problems. Reporting the *precise* error you get when you download the 64-bit would be helpful. So would telling us how you're trying to do it (clicking a link in a Web browser, using a torrent, etc.)

It is possible to run a 32-bit Linux from a 64-bit EFI. If Boot Repair can't handle it, that's a Boot Repair issue. Getting it to work will require an understanding of your current setup and knowledge of [EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) generally (or your specific boot loader in particular). Since you haven't said how your boot process is failing, it's hard to offer specific suggestions on fixing it.

That said, running a 32-bit Linux on a 64-bit EFI is sub-optimal, so upgrading to a 64-bit installation is definitely the preferred way to go.